# How to initialize List<Short> in one line?

Tags: java, list, initialization, short, list-initialization

How to initialize a list of short elements in one line?

Something like this:

```
List<Short> numbers = new ArrayList<Short>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

But I am getting:

```
"Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayList(java.util.List<E>)'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Integer.shortValue()` method: Like below

```
  List<Short> numbers = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(value -> value.shortValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

The type `ArrayList` is declared as:

```
public class ArrayList<E> ... {
    public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) { ... }
}
```

That means in your statement

```
List<Short> numbers = new ArrayList<>( ... );
```

the argument that you pass into the constructor must be of type `Collection<? extends Short>`. But you are passing a

```
List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

which is of type `List<Integer>`. Note that integral literals are `int` by default. Unfortunately, there is no *short* way to make them `short`. But you can always cast them:

```
List<Short> numbers = new ArrayList<>(List.of((short) 1, (short) 2, (short) 3, (short) 4, (short) 5));
```

This compiles fine.

Side note: Why do you need to create another list object (`new ArrayList(...)`) while already having one (`List.of(...)`)?

Comment: `List.of` creates an immutable list. Wrapping it into a new `ArrayList` makes it mutable again

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thank you for the answer. I am creating another list object, because I want to explicitly tell JVM that I want my list to be an Array List, due to accessing elements.

Comment: Hmmm ... But why?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Because if I leave it only as `List.of` my accessing an element operation is slower rather than using `ArrayList`.

Comment: No, that is not true!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose but why?

Comment: The question is, why do you think, that one is _slower_ than the other!